# check if vector crosses a closed plan

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am working on a 3D view, I have a shape in a plan that is set in space.
In theory I would need to do it for any shape, but let's start with a rectangle ABCD.

Let's call the 4 points A,B,C,D, with coordinates Xa,Ya,Za; Xb,Yb,Yc; Xc,Yc,Zc and Xd,Yd,Zd.

Then I have a vector, defined by 2 points P1 and P2.

I need to check if that vector goes through rectangle.
I already can say where the vector meets the rectangle's plan, but how can I check if the point is inside the shape or outside?

Comment: Are the given shapes 2D?

Comment: @Jamāl the given shapes are represented in 3D (x,y,z coordinates), but they are on a unique plane.

Comment: In general, you could calculate the sign of the value when inserting the (xyz) values in the lines equations that define the rectangle.

Comment: @Moti I almost could solve the problem (ok for rectangle).what I did for now, is to "report" all dots to the plan defined by the shape(rectangle), so I have a plan X,Y, and my dot in center. So it works for rectangle, now am looking a way to do it for any shape defined by a list of points... not the same, but reporting all on the plan, it is much easier already.

Comment: @Moti I guess I will close the question, because I could solve it except for specific shapes, but this is another question already...